# Object is not projected on Weight Paint

Tags: objects, 3d-view, weight-painting

normally it shows the triangles on the Weight Paint but it dosent.
Does somone know why?

[image: Triangles not shown on Weight Paint]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it. I had to creat a new Triangle Object and Check the following Boxes.

[image: 2_Box]
[image: 1_Box]